# Test path fails to check for folder path

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-remoting

I am trying to check if a specific folders exists in the remote servers.I have file PathList.txt which contains the server address and folder paths to check.But the test path fails even on my local computer(I give my local machine IP).It says path does not exits when the path actually exists

```
$ServerPaths = Get-Content .\PathList.txt

#Check for paths in servers.
Foreach ($s in $ServerPaths)
{
   $Server,$Paths = $s.split('=',2)
   $AllPaths = $Paths -split ','
   $Server=$Server.Trim()

   Foreach ($Path in $AllPaths)
  {  
     $Path=$Path.Trim()

     $CheckPath = "\\"+$Server+"\"+$Path

     if(Test-Path $CheckPath)
     {
         Write-host $Server $Path "Path exists"
     }
     else
     {
         Write-host $Server $Path "Path does not exists"  
     } 

   }

 }
```

PathList.txt contains

```
10.247.211.12 = D$\Install, D$\Dir
```

Comment: I don't see anything fundamentally wrong with your code. Did you check that `$CheckPath` has the correct value(s) and that you can access the paths manually?

Comment: Agree, go back to the basics: and just run the command:
`Test-Path "\\10.247.211.12\D$\Install"`
Or
`Test-Path "\\Localhost\D$\Install"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked your code and it works fine, but only if you have accessed the path before (so it could cache credentials), or if your current user can access the share. I suggest you to add `-Credential` parameter to your `Test-Path` call.